# Making images take up all space available in a div

Tags: html, css

Say that I have images contained inside a list, as below.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x400">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x200">
    </li> 
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x200">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x400">
    </li>
</ul>
```

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VpcBY/2/) shows what the setup would look like on a page. Is it possible using only CSS to make the second and third list items take up space to the right of the first? If not possible within a list structure, what changes would I need to make to the HTML to make it possible? The solution would ideally work no matter how many images were present in the list.

edit: the image below shows the sort of thing that I'm looking for. The left is what I currently have (as shown in the fiddle), but I would like to have it look like the right hand side of the image.
[image]

Comment: what type of structure do you want? explain in simple words.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VpcBY/6/  `ul li{
    display: inline
}`? http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/horizontal_master.htm

Comment: The solution greatly depends on whether or not the images are always known (quantity, dimensions, etc.).  If you're looking to have an unknown number of images of unknown dimensions in an unknown order, there is no pure CSS solution to get the images to fit together (you're looking for *Masonry*).

Comment: The images will be pretty much the same shape, at least. The width of each image is adjusted such that it takes up some fixed proportion of the `div` containing it. I'm not necessarily looking for the images to fit together particularly well, I just don't want them to display in a single column down the left of the page. I'll have a look at masonry - thanks.

Comment: Check out the demo ( http://jsfiddle.net/VpcBY/8/ )  presented in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17047929/209427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `float` property and set `li` to `float: left;`

```
ul li {
    float: left;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VpcBY/8/)**

I'd warmly recommend the following [article about `float`s](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

#### Eplanation:

Adding a `float` property to these images basically sets their behavior to the following:

- They will get `block` display type ( `display: block;` )
- They won't take up as much space as `block` elements (or `li`) would normally do, but they will shrink to:

  - a size explicitly set to them (if there is such)
  - to a size that fits their !non-floated! content
- If the `float`ed element has space near a previously `float`ed element, it will be displayed near it (on the same "row") rather then displaying it on the next "line" as block elements normally behave

#### On the other hand

I guess you are more like after a mosaic layout, to cover your available space regardless of image sizes.

This you can **only accomplish with js**. One of the libs I'd recommend are [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/VpcBY/5/

You need something like that?

```
 ul li 
 {
    float: left;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the vertical-align property and set img to vertical-align: top:

```
img {vertical-align: top;}
```

Please view the [DEMO](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/dDCne).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left !important; 
}
```